# Category theory from the first order logic point of view

Tags: logic, category-theory, model-theory, foundations

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Obj}{Obj}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Arr}{Arr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Dom}{Dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cod}{Cod}$

MacLane defines "metacategories" purely axiomaticaly. When we look at it from perspective of first order logic we see that "metacategories" is a first order theory consisting following signature:

- two unary predicates $\Obj,\Arr$
- two unary functions $\Dom,\Cod$
- binary function $\circ$
- unary function $\Id$

and axioms for domain, codomain, composition unity. I wrote this axioms in the appendix.

Next, we can define a **category** as a model in this first order theory. Given two categories, we can also define a **functor** as a structure map.

> **Question.** Is there some source which treats the whole category theory from this point of view?

For example I do not know how to define natural transformation in this language.

---

**Appendix.** Axioms for category theory :

- $(\forall f)(\Arr(f) \rightarrow (\Obj(\Dom(f)) \wedge \Obj((\Cod(f)))$
- $(\forall f,g)((\Arr(f)\wedge\Arr(g)\wedge\Cod(f)=\Dom(g))\rightarrow \Arr(g\circ f))$
- $(\forall a)(\Obj(a)\rightarrow((\Arr(\Id(a))\wedge \Dom(\Id(a))=a=\Cod(\Id(a))\wedge (\forall f)(\Arr(f)\rightarrow ((\Dom(f)=a\rightarrow f\circ\Id(a)=f)\wedge(\Cod(f)=a\rightarrow \Id(a)\circ f=f))))$
- $(\forall f,g,h)((\Arr(f)\wedge\Arr(g)\wedge\Arr(h)\wedge\Cod(f)=\Dom(g)\wedge \Cod(g)=\Dom(h))\rightarrow h\circ ((g\circ f) = (h\circ g)\circ f))$

Comment: You mean $\operatorname{Obj}(a)\to\ldots$ in the third axiom, I suppose

Comment: What's $\text{Arr}$?

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek: I presume $\mathrm{Obj}(a)$ is interpreted to mean that $a$ is an object and $\mathrm{Arr}(f)$ is interpreted to mean that $f$ is an arrow.

Comment: Maybe a two-sorted language could be more appropriate here since in category theory, asking what $Dom(a)$ is when $a$ is an object can seem weird.

Comment: You might want to include an axiom like
$$(\forall x)(\mathrm{Obj}(x) \Leftrightarrow \neg \mathrm{Arr}(x))$$
to ensure that everything is an object, or a morphism, but not both. Another possibility is to say that *every* element is an arrow, and refer to objects by instead referring to their identity arrows. *Another* possibility is to use [first-order logic with dependent sorts](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/makkai/folds/foldsinpdf/FOLDS.pdf), which is perhaps more natural from the perspective of a category theorist.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: That's what I meant by "refer to objects by instead referring to their identity arrows". It's a slick solution to the problem. I prefer FOLDS because it feels closer to the way that category theorists think when they're doing category theory in practice, but it has the down-side of being less well understood than standard non-dependent first-order logic (single-sorted or otherwise).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You are right.

Comment: @Max But can't you restrict $\text{Dom}$ and \text{Cod}$ to only act on morphisms?

Comment: @CliveNewstead Sorry, I misread your comment.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek: In (single-sorted) first-order logic, a function symbol (such as Dom and Cod here) is just a symbol, which is 'thought of' as a function, but is really just a symbol. There is no way of saying it has a particular domain or codomain. When you interpret the theory in a model, the function symbol is interpreted as an actual function, but its domain and codomain is the entire (underlying set of) the model. So if you can only distinguish between objects and morphisms by applying a predicate, your function symbols need to be defined on both objects and morphisms (and anything else).

Comment: @CliveNewstead Ahhh, okay, thank you for clearing that up! In response to that I really support your previous recommendation to turn everything into a morphism and have objects be their identity arrows :)

Comment: You're not really going to find a first order treatment of categories that will talk about objects, morphisms, functors, and natural transformations all in the same breath, unless you're axiomatizing the 2-category of categories or something. Colin McLarty's *Elementary Categories, Elementary Toposes* mostly approaches categories as models of the first order theory above, though, and tries to avoid delving too deep into the universe these models live in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would be very unusual, for two important reasons.

First, *models in sets are not enough*. It is important to consider *large* categories, such as **Set** or **AbGrp** or **Top** or **Cat**.

Secondly, category theory develops its own take on first-order logic — it would be a wasted effort (and somewhat counter-philosophical) to study the subject in the traditional set-oriented version of logic.

However, one *does* study categories as models — we call such a thing an *internal categories*.

---

Regarding your specific note on natural transformations, there are several paths that might lead you there.

The first is that you can show the product has a right adjoint, so that there is a natural bijection

$$ \hom(\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{D}, \mathcal{E}) \cong \hom(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{E}^{\mathcal{D}}) $$

This means that you can treat $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$ as the *category* of morphisms from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. A natural transformation, then, is an arrow in this category.

A similar phenomenon happens, for example, in abelian groups, which allows you to construct the *abelian group* of morphisms from one group to another.

Now, assuming you didn't think to show that, one can still draw *inspiration* from it; since arrows can be viewed as morphisms $\hom(\uparrow, \mathcal{C})$, where $\uparrow$ means the arrow category, even if you didn't know that $\mathcal{E}^\mathcal{D}$ existed, one can still draw inspiration from the idea of the adjunction above and define a natural transformation to be a morphism $\uparrow \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$.

And this whole thing is similar to topology, and one might be tempted to mimic the definition of a homotopy.

Comment: To be clear, the cartesian closure condition holds for *small* categories but usually not for locally small or large categories. So "arrow in $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbf{Set}$" can't be used, but the "inspired" approach of a functor $\uparrow\times\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}$ works fine. Of course this is only an issue if one wants to capture non-small categories. As you point out, to do this requires considering something more than normal set theoretic models (at least in a "usual" set theory).

Comment: I agree with your first reason, but I think considering models beyond $\mathbf{Set}$ doesn't lead to any contradiction. 

As for the second one. I can't see why this approach is a waste of effort. I believe that intertwining theories is not always a bad idea. In our case, I was just curious how Godel Completeness Theorem would look like applied to category theory (treated as a first order theory).

Answer (score 8):

First-order PA and first-order ZF are usually presented as mono-sortal -- in PA, *every* "thing" (every object in the domain of quantification) is a "number", and in ZF, "every" thing is a set.  A first-order category theory, if trying to preserve this practice, could become a mono-sortal first-order "arrow theory".  One could shrink the signature presented in the axiomatization above by eliminating the Arr predicate, since every thing, including objects, could be an arrow -- the objects would be the id-arrows.  In that treatment, every arrow goes from one id-arrow to another id-arrow, and id-arrows are the ones that go from themselves to themselves (i.e. are fixpoints of both the domain/"source" and codomain/"target" operators). A group could be a monoid where all the arrows go from and to the same one object, which is a distinguished arrow that is the group's identity element and is defined to compose with all the others accordingly.  All of the "actual structure" of a category would be in a model's definition of the composition operator. Unfortunately, since that operator is partial (if there is more than one object in the category, it is possible for some arrows not to compose with others at all because their target and source don't dovetail), the resulting axiomatization would need to write composition as a ternary predicate since the usual definition of a  first-order language doesn't allow "partial" term-constructors.

William Hatcher gave this as a first-order axiomatization.

> C.1. $\forall x_1[ d(c(x_1)) = c(x_1) \wedge c(d(x_1)) = d(x_1) ]$
>
> The domain of the codomain of $x_1$ is the codomain of $x_1$,
>     and the codomain of the domain of $x_1$ is the domain of $x_1$.
>
> C.2. $\forall x_1x_2x_3x_4 [ K(x_1,x_2,x_3) \wedge  K(x_1,x_2,x_4)\rightarrow  x_3=x_4]$
>
> The composition of $x_1$ with $x_2$ is unique when it is defined.
>
> C.3. $\forall x_1x_2[ \exists x_3[ K(x1,x2,x3)]\leftrightarrow c(x_1)=d(x_2)$ ]
>
> The composition of $x_1$ with $x_2$ is defined if and only
>     if the codomain of $x_1$ is the domain of $x_2$.
>
> C.4. $\forall x_1x_2x_3[ K(x_1,x_2,x_3)\rightarrow  d(x_3)=d(x_1) \wedge c(x_3)=c(x_2) ]$
>
> If $x_3$ is the composition of $x_1$ with $x_2$ then the
>     domain of $x_3$ is the domain of $x_1$ and the codomain of $x_3$ is the codomain of $x_2$.
>
> C.5.$\forall x_1[ K(d(x_1),x_1,x_1) \wedge  K(x_1,c(x_1),x_1)]$
>
> For any $x_1$, the domain of $x_1$ is a left identity
>   for $x_1$ under composition and the codomain is a right identity.
>
> C.6. $\forall x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7 [ ( K(x_1,x_2,x_4) \wedge K(x_2,x_3,x_5)     \wedge K(x_1,x_5,x_6) \wedge K(x_4,x_3,x_7) )\\\rightarrow x_6=x_7 ]$
>   Composition is associative when it is defined.

Any model of this theory is a category.  Unfortunately, however, that would beg the question of what to use as a model-construction language. First-order logic is typically associated with models constructed in a set theory such as ZF. That would defeat the whole purpose of this as an alternative foundation, as well as limiting us to "small" or "internal" categories.