# Is the theory of sheaves a first order theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Is the theory of sheaves a first order theory?
How should I check if a theory is first order or not?

Comment: Maybe useful the post [Category theory from the first order logic point of view](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383503/category-theory-from-the-first-order-logic-point-of-view)

Comment: For a version of first-order language of categories, see William Hatcher, [The Logical Foundations of Mathematics (Pergamon Press, 1982)](https://books.google.it/books?id=wf3iBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA237), Ch.8, But I'm not an expert ... (-:

Comment: Sheaves on a fixed topological space (or site, even): yes. But that is not what people usually mean by sheaf theory.